# Attempting to produce linear approximation table. Values in output are incorrect

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption, cryptography, des

Here is a code given in c language, and the s box table is  {0xE, 0x4, 0xD, 0x1, 0x2, 0xF, 0xB, 0x8, 0x3, 0xA, 0x6, 0xC, 0x5, 0x9, 0x0, 0x7};, when we run this code we get the wrong output. We should get the linear approximation table from this code. I think the error that I get is here at the sbox output part.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef unsigned short int UINT16; 

UINT16  sbox_table[16] =  {0xE, 0x4, 0xD, 0x1, 0x2, 0xF, 0xB, 0x8, 0x3, 0xA, 0x6, 0xC, 0x5, 0x9, 0x0, 0x7}; 

int lin_appr_table[16][16];


void construct_lin_appr_table()
{
    UINT16 i, j, k;

    UINT16 X, Y, x;
    UINT16 X_xor, Y_xor;
    int counter;

    for (i=0 ; i<16 ; i++)//sbox input
    {
        
        for (j=0 ; j<16 ; j++)//sbox output
        {
            X=i;
            Y=j;
            
            counter=0;
            for (k=0;k<16;k++)
            {
              X_xor=X&k;
              Y_xor=Y&sbox_table[k];
              
              if(X_xor^Y_xor==0) counter++;
              
             
            }
            
            lin_appr_table[i][j]=counter-8;
            
            //Write the code that makes up the table

        }

    }

    //Write the code that printed the table on the screen
    
    
    for (i=0 ; i<16 ; i++)//sbox input
    {
        for (j=0 ; j<16 ; j++)//sbox output
        {
            printf("% d ", lin_appr_table[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}  

int main()
{
    construct_lin_appr_table();
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: Watch out for operator precedence in `if(X_xor^Y_xor==0)`. Did you mean `if((X_xor^Y_xor)==0)`?

Comment: Is `X_xor=X&k` supposed to be `X_xor = X & (1 << k)`? Just a guess.

Comment: Can you edit the post here to show what expected output is?  (I see you almost posted that as answer, but it would be good to have here.)

Comment: it is a image and i cant post it here

Comment: how can i show your in another way that expected output?

Comment: Pictures, although not always appropriate are not forbidden when information cannot be conveyed in another way.  Post a picture if you have to.

Comment: ...and this table is  the result specifically for the inputs values of: `sbox_table[16] = {0xE, 0x4, 0xD, 0x1, 0x2, 0xF, 0xB, 0x8, 0x3, 0xA, 0x6, 0xC, 0x5, 0x9, 0x0, 0x7};` ?

Comment: the purpose of this is: the code above does not give us this expected table, the purpose is to find the errors within the code in order to take this table (expected table) as output.

Comment: Well, that clears it up.  This is not a C problem, rather it is a  or algorithm problem.  I suggest posting this question on [cryptography stack exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).  There will likely be more relevant expertise there.

Comment: Thank you for recomandation. Hope to get an answer

Comment: Possible [ref](http://www.cs.bc.edu/~straubin/crypto2017/heys.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key code change: see `//if ((X_xor ^ Y_xor) == 0)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef unsigned short int UINT16;

const UINT16 sbox_table[16] = {0xE, 0x4, 0xD, 0x1, 0x2, 0xF, 0xB, 0x8, 0x3, 0xA,
    0x6, 0xC, 0x5, 0x9, 0x0, 0x7};

int lin_appr_table[16][16];

// There exist various hacks to quickly count the ones in an integer.
// This is just a simple loop.
unsigned count1(unsigned i) {
  unsigned count = 0;
  while (i) {
    count += i & 1;
    i >>= 1;
  }
  return count;
}

void construct_lin_appr_table() {
  UINT16 i, j, k;
  UINT16 X, Y; //, x;
  UINT16 X_xor, Y_xor;
  int counter;

  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
      X = i;
      Y = j;

      counter = 0;
      for (k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
        X_xor = X & k;
        Y_xor = Y & sbox_table[k];

        //if ((X_xor ^ Y_xor) == 0)
        //if ((count1(X_xor) - count1(Y_xor)) % 2 == 0)
        if ((count1(X_xor ^ Y_xor) & 1) == 0)
          counter++;
      }
      lin_appr_table[i][j] = counter - 16 / 2;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
      printf("% d ", lin_appr_table[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  construct_lin_appr_table();
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
 8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0  0 -2 -2  0  0 -2  6  2  2  0  0  2  2  0  0 
 0  0 -2 -2  0  0 -2 -2  0  0  2  2  0  0 -6  2 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2 -6 -2 -2  2  2 -2 -2 
 0  2  0 -2 -2 -4 -2  0  0 -2  0  2  2 -4  2  0 
 0 -2 -2  0 -2  0  4  2 -2  0 -4  2  0 -2 -2  0 
 0  2 -2  4  2  0  0  2  0 -2  2  4 -2  0  0 -2 
 0 -2  0  2  2 -4  2  0 -2  0  2  0  4  2  0  2 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -2  2  2 -2  2 -2 -2 -6 
 0  0 -2 -2  0  0 -2 -2 -4  0 -2  2  0  4  2 -2 
 0  4 -2  2 -4  0  2 -2  2  2  0  0  2  2  0  0 
 0  4  0 -4  4  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
 0 -2  4 -2 -2  0  2  0  2  0  2  4  0  2  0 -2 
 0  2  2  0 -2  4  0  2 -4 -2  2  0  2  0  0  2 
 0  2  2  0 -2 -4  0  2 -2  0  0 -2 -4  2 -2  0 
 0 -2 -4 -2 -2  0  2  0  0 -2  4 -2 -2  0  2  0
```

[Ref](http://www.cs.bc.edu/%7Estraubin/crypto2017/heys.pdf)

See [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer) for a faster `count1()`.

Comment: it is working. thanks a lot for helping me. i really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest the following two changes to produce table below:

> 1. 

```
      //if(X_xor^Y_xor==0) counter++;
      if((X_xor^Y_xor)==0) counter++;
```

Note: for above statement, turning warnings on should result in something similar to:

```
36, 19    warning: ^ has lower precedence than ==; == will be evaluated first
```

> 2. 

```
      //X_xor=X&k;
      X_xor = X & (1 << k); //credit to Weather Vane in comments
```

result in following table:

[image]

Asides:  As a rule it is also a good idea to initialize your variables during declaration, and always before use.  eg:

```
int lin_appr_table[16][16] = {{0}};//initializes all locations to 0
```

And when able, choose to use portable over [non-portable](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-getchar-getch-getc-getche/) code:

```
    getchar(); //portable
    //getch(); //not portable
```

Comment: when i made that change i get another table.

Comment: If you are referring the `^` change, then yes, that would result in different values.  Are you saying it is preferred to evaluate `Y_xor==0` first?  ( i.e.:  `X_xor^(Y_xor==0)` ) as the intended evaluation?

Comment: can i get an mail or something else to discuss there about this problem

Comment: @S.Nesimi - no.  unfortunately that will not work.  Just post the expected output somewhere below the code section in the original post, and add additional explanation there as well about the correct algorithm